# Eager loading nested property not working in Entity Framework 6

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, eager-loading

I have a service method that returns a list of user summaries:

```
public IEnumerable<UserSummary> GetUserSummaries()
{
    return Users.Include(u => u.BillingAddress)
        .Include(u => u.BillingAddress.Country)
        .OrderBy(u => u.Email).Select(u => new UserSummary
        {
            Id = u.Id,
            UserName = u.UserName,
            Email = u.Email,
            BillingAddress = u.BillingAddress,
            Approved = u.Approved,
            Admin = u.Admin,
            Roles = u.Roles.Select(r => r.Name)
        });
}
```

This issue I'm having is that the `BillingAddress.Country` is not eager-loading as I've explicitly specified. Since I'm not doing a `.ToList()`, I am getting an **InvalidOperationException: There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first.**

If I do a `ToList()`, the exception goes away, but then instead of 1 query, it becomes n+1 queries because it lazy loads the Country.

How do I eager load the Country for the BillingAddress and avoid the n+1 queries?

---

Update: I had a suspicion that because I was not projecting the `Country` on the the `UserSummary` it was being ignored, despite being explicitly included. I added a `Country` property to the `UserSummary` class and projected the country onto it. It is now included in the original query.

Is there a way to get it to load into the `UserSummary.BillingAddress.Country` rather than including it as a separate property?

Comment: Try to use `.Include(u => u.BillingAddress.Select(a => a.Country))`

Comment: Unless I'm missing a special Linq reference, `Select` appears to only be available on collections.

Answer (score 0):

```
Users.Include("BillingAddress.Country")
```